# How to write strings into excel file with openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm a beginner at programming. I'm trying to make a system like Readwise(it collects highlights from Kindle and sends a bunch of highlights to your email) for myself as my first project. Right now I'm trying to make a part where I take out highlights from an html file exported from Kindle, and write them into an excel file. I think I somehow managed to do the first part but I get this error on the second part.

```
TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>
```

I believe this means that I can't write strings into the file with my code. Could you tell me what I can do here?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

with open("test.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

    note_tags = soup.find_all("div", class_="noteText")
    for note in note_tags:
        highlights = note.text
        print(highlights)

    wb = load_workbook('highlights.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(highlights)
    wb.save
```

I tried to use Pandas instead because as the next step I wanna make sure that it won't write duplicates and it seems easier to do with Pandas. But every time I run the script the excel file got corrupted and I got a "at least one sheet must be visible" error.

Comment: The error message really is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ws.append()` expects the `highlights` to be a "list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict." as the error says. But in your example, you give it a string. If you just want the string from `highlights` in the first column of your Excel. You could just make it into a list (with just 1 item) by putting highlights between square brackets, so `[highlights]`. Adding a row to the Excel file then becomes `ws.append([highlights])`. Now you are appending a list instead of a string.

But the other problem (I guess) I see, is that you have several notes that you loop over, but your current code only appends the last iteration over `for note in note_tags:` to the Excel file. I assume you want every note as a new ROW in Excel (not a new column), so you want to `append()` every iteration over note_tags to your excel-file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

with open("test.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

    # Open Excel file
    wb = load_workbook('highlights.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    note_tags = soup.find_all("div", class_="noteText")
    for note in note_tags:
        highlights = note.text
        print(highlights)
        ws.append([highlights])  # Add line to a new row in Excel

    wb.save('highlights.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for the explanation and the revised code. It is very helpful for a beginner like me. You're correct. As you say I do have several notes. I tried your code and it didn't give me any error. But it seems like nothing has been written in the file. I can see highlights on my terminal so I think the variable "highlights" has notes in it. Do you know what the problem is? Feel free to tell me if you need more information. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `wb.save()` part wasn't correct. Could you try again?

Comment: Hi. It worked perfectly! Thanks very much! I hope I'm not asking you too much but could you tell me why ws.append([highlights]) as opposed to ws.append(highlights) allow me to add a new row?

Comment: Yes, I added some more explanation in the first paragraph. By putting highlights betwee brackets (`[highlights]`) it becomes a list (with just 1 item). `ws.append()` needs to have a list, tuple, range of dict, which `[highlights]` now is.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: If your question is answer/problem solved you can mark the answer as "answered". That way others don't have to look if the question is still open/unsolved or not.